# Apparent character limit for files.list search string in Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am using Python to access my Google Drive account via the Google Drive API. I would like to list only those files whose names start with a certain long character string. To do this, I am using the `files.list` `contains` clause, as described in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters). I have discovered that this approach does not work as expected when the search string exceeds 26 characters.

To replicate, do the following:

1. Set up a Google Drive service account.
2. Create a folder in your Google Drive account and give the service account access.
3. Upload two empty files to this folder, one named `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1` and another named `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza1`.
4. Use the API to list the files in the folder, first matching on files that contain `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` and then on files that contain `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza`. The first search expectedly returns both files, however the second search should return the second file but instead returns none.

Here is the Python code I used to test:

```
import httplib2
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from apiclient import discovery

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
folder = '1mkebcpZ-mIhq4dLWwePqHqwzw6kUAj1-'

prefix = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

results = service.files().list(
    fields="files(id, name)",
    q="'%s' in parents and name contains '%s'" % (folder, prefix)
).execute()

print('First result:')
print(results['files'])

prefix = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza'

results = service.files().list(
    fields="files(id, name)",
    q="'%s' in parents and name contains '%s'" % (folder, prefix)
).execute()

print('Second result:')
print(results['files'])
```

Here is my output:

```
First result:
[{u'id': u'1Wwzym1ZVMTWzuX-K0eT0-xJrWI8t_YGN', u'name': u'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza1'}, {u'id': u'16i4SSwYSbhV9hCFUaCwE7nrYdxBntIi_', u'name': u'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1'}]
Second result:
[]
```

Why doesn't the file `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza1` appear in the second result?

Comment: Could you provide the console log?